# 2x2 subfigures instead of 4 rows with subcaption package

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I'm working on a 2x2 subfigure figure and they keep appearing in 4 rows instead of 2x2. What am I doing wrong?

Code underneath (and some of the included packages):

```
\usepackage{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth ]{pic/fig_flexibility.png}
\caption{Customizability graph}\label{fig:flexibility}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth ]{pic/privacy_graph.png}
\caption{Privacy graph}\label{fig:privacy_graph}
\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth ]{pic/load_balancing_graph.png}
\caption{Resource impact distribution graph}\label{fig:load_balancing_graph}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth ]{pic/failure_sensitivity_graph.png}
\caption{Failure sensitivity graph}\label{fig:failure_sensitivity_graph}
\end{subfigure} %

\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, I fear that when I do get them 2x2 they won't be the same height. Any handy tricks I can use for that?

Comment: Try removing the blank lines